# Bookdown: Number each part starting from 1 or use Arabic numbers for appendices

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I am using `bookdown` to present the materials for a university module and would like to have a section for lectures (numbered from 1 to 10) and one for seminars (again numbered from 1 to 10). I have two ideas for how to solve this, but can't get either to work:

- have two PARTs and have the chapter numbering start from 1 within each of them
- show seminars as appendices and number the appendices with Arabic numerals

Can either of these work in bookdown? If not, is there anything else I can do? If I can number chapters with letters and then subchapters with numbers, that might also work, but one of the other ways would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

For the `bookdown::gitbook` format you may use jQuery to 'post-process' the output. It's hacky but I think it's somewhat more elegant than the approach you uploaded to GitHub. Here's how it goes:

Setup your .Rmd like his:

**.Rmd**

```yaml
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Me"
date:  "today"
site: "bookdown::bookdown_site"
output: 
  bookdown::gitbook:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
---

# Lectures

## A
text

## B
text

# Seminars

## D
text

## E
text

# (APPENDIX) Appendix {-} 

# Your Appendix
```

**header.html**

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  
   $('.summary > li > a > b, h1 > span, h1').each(function() {
      var temp = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(temp.replace(/(\d|^\s)/, ''));
    });

   $('nav > ul > li > ul > li b, :header > span').each(function() {
      var temp = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(temp.replace(/(\d\.)+/, ''));
    });
      
  });
</script>
```

After the document is ready, the above script will remove section numbers and whitespace at the beginning of the first level headers (RegExp pattern `(\d|^\s)`). For the second-level headers, the section numbers are modified such that a digit followed by a period one or more times (RegExp pattern `/(\d\.)+/`) is removed. Appendices remain untouched (as long as you number them alphabetically).

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that is indeed a bit more elegant. Would it leave appendices untouched? Or would I need to complicate this yet again if I want appendices numbered with letters?

Comment: This requires just a small 'complication' :). I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to do this within `bookdown`, but have now written a script that post-processes the HTML files that are created.  I am sharing this here in case someone faces a similar issue - of course, it might break at any time if any of the class names in the HTML output are changed.

https://github.com/LukasWallrich/StMarysSocPsy/blob/master/R/number_appendices.R

Suggestions for how to do this within bookdown would still be most welcome. I have also raised an issue on Github, no response so far: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/950